# Applet Painting

Tags: java

Im trying to get the point of the cursor in the paint part and simply draw an oval. No luck though!

```
public void paint(Graphics g){
     Point ComponentPoint = PaintPanel.getLocationOnScreen();
     Point CursorPoint=   MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation(); //gets cursor point

     int ComPX =  ComponentPoint.x;
     int ComPY =  ComponentPoint.y;
     int CurPX =  CursorPoint.x;
     int CurPY =  CursorPoint.y;
     int FinalX = CurPX - ComPX;
     int FinalY =  CurPY - ComPY;
     g.drawOval(FinalX, FinalY, 20, 20);
}

private void PaintPanelMouseDragged(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                        
    //when mouse is moved over paintpanel

    //PaintPanel.repaint();
    not working
}
```

This is it without paint method, the image:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/VOyhr.png

Comment: Consider creating and posting a small *almost* working example, your best attempt at a solution, in other words, an [sscce](http://sscce.org).

Comment: With what I posted it doesnt show anything :/ I tried something else and it got rid of everything but drew the oval.

Comment: It's hard to know what to make of the little bit of code you've posted without some context. That's why I'm asking you to provide some of that context by creating a very small but compilable and runnable program.

Answer (score 1):

You can't add code in the paint method like that. YOu would not reference the MouseInfo class in the paint method since you have no control over when the paint() method is invoked. You should be using a MouseListener and MouseMotionListner to do custom painting. Also, custom painting should not be done in the paint method.

See [Custom Painting Approaches](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/05/08/custom-painting-approaches/) for two solutions.

Comment: And [How to write mouse listeners](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/mouselistener.html)